# JSON web token auth logic with refresh tokens

Tags: angular, security, oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt

Angular 4 application running in browser (website backend), displaying from the server data owned by particular user.
Server: PHP+MySQL, Zend Framework 3 + Doctrine ORM

Naming:

- `access_token`: Short lifetime (1 min), allows to access personal resources, carries user_id, base64 encoded, json web token spec valid.
- `refresh_token`: Long lifetime (1 week) allows to retrieve new access_token without providing credentials, stored in db, can be revoked by admin if needed.

Main point of using refresh_tokens is to be logged in longer than `access_token` short lifetime (possibly forever if `refresh_token` expiration time is updated each time user authorization happens), user needs to provide credentials only in case of inactivity longer than `refresh_token` lifetime.
Refresh tokens are stored in db, so can be easily revoked.

### 1. Browser tries to authenticate

REQUEST:

- username and password
- sent to /api/auth

RESPONSE:

Username and password is validated and checked against database

If valid:

- `access_token` is generated with expiration time 60sec
- `user_id` is encoded into access_token
- `refresh_token` is generated (random string) and saved to db, expiration time 1 week, (refresh_token is not included in access_token, it's a separate key)
- HTTP 200 OK

If invalid:

- HTTP 401 Unauthorized

ACTION AFTER

IF valid:

- access_token and `refresh_token` stored in browser (private member varialbe of auth service, browser's local storage).

Looks like it's not a good idea to store `refresh_token` in local storage - but this allows for "keep me signed in". If stored only per browser session in private member variable, user would need to log in every time opens the browser. Any ideas?

If invalid:

- display errors, suggest to retry

### 2. Browser requests protected data from server

REQUEST:

- sends access_token
- to /api/resource

RESPONSE:

- if access_token is valid, json data are sent, HTTP 200 OK
- if access_token is invalid (eg. unable to decode), HTTP 400 Bad Request
- if access_token expired, HTTP 401 Unauthorized

ACTION AFTER RESPONSE:

- if HTTP 200: data displayed
- if HTTP 400: redirected to login page
- if HTTP 401: retry to obtain new access_token using refresh_token stored in browser

### 3. Retry to autenticate using refresh_token (after HTTP 401 Unauthorized)

REQUEST:

- access_token
- refresh_token

RESPONSE:

- Validate `access_token` (everything except expiration time, using \Firebase\JWT)
- Validate `refresh_token` against database (user_id decoded from access_token, the string and expiration time)

If valid:

Generate new refresh_token, save to database, update ttl (or should be the same token, only updated ttl?)
Generate new access_token
HTTP 200 OK

If invalid:

HTTP 401 Unauthorized

ACTIONS AFTER RESPONSE:

If valid:

- store the new access_key and refresh_key in browser
- retry the previous resource request using new access_key

If invalid:

- display login page

## Questions

The key point I don't like is that access_token and refresh_token are stored in the same place and sent the same way. Maybe there is another way to do it?

- is this logic sensible?
- are there any security flaws, assuming this happens in web app?
- should I store both the tokens in browser's local storage?
- should `refresh_token` be encoded in `access_token`? If they are still saved in the same place, looks that it may be incorporated into access_token. Any reasons not to do it?
- when should I update `refresh_token` lifetime?
- any open source projects to see similar authentication in action?
- any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding where to store tokens and the security flaws (taken from Github user *brettpostin* https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2039#issuecomment-288135399) keep in mind that:

- Storing tokens in localStorage is susceptible to **xss**.
- Storing tokens in cookies is susceptible to **csrf**.

Best option is to protect against both as described here:
http://www.redotheweb.com/2015/11/09/api-security.html

Store your tokens in http-only cookies and use a suitable targeted **csrf** defense as suggested here:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

> when should I update refresh_token lifetime?

If you are asking **when to update the refresh token** it depends on the implementation of your protocol, for example Google Auth server issued Refresh tokens never expire, they are revoked when the user revokes access to the app. But may I suggest a few weeks, so you don't lose control over it.

> any open source projects to see similar authentication in action?

Well, you can download any project that uses OAuth2, for example this project on github: https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server

> any other suggestions?

Have a look at OpenID Connect and Identity Providers (IDPs) such as Keycloack.

Hope this helps you in any way.